# Python Selenium "Can not connect to the Service %s" % self.path in linux server

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

```html
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "testing.py", line 20, in <module>
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="/home/cavema11/public_html/testing.py")
  File "/opt/python-3.6.4/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/chrome/webdriver.py", line 68, in __init__
    self.service.start()
  File "/opt/python-3.6.4/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py", line 104, in start
    raise WebDriverException("Can not connect to the Service %s" % self.path)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Can not connect to the Service /home/cavema11/public_html/testing.py
```

I have 127.0.0.1 localhost in my /etc/hosts but still getting this errors.

Please help me.

Thank you

Comment: Did you check the service is online?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Through the argument `executable_path` you need to pass the absolute path of the *ChromeDriver* instead of any other file. So you need to change:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="/home/cavema11/public_html/testing.py")
```

To:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='/path/to/chromedriver')
```

---

### Update

- Ensure that you have downloaded the exact format of the *ChromeDriver* binary from the [download location](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=2.39/) pertaining to your underlying OS among:

  - **chromedriver_linux64.zip**: For *Linux OS*
  - **chromedriver_mac64.zip**: For *Mac OSX*
  - **chromedriver_win32.zip**: For *Windows OS*
- Ensure that `/etc/hosts` file contains the following entry:

  ```
  127.0.0.1 localhost
  ```
- Ensure that *ChromeDriver* binary have executable permission for the **non-root**  user.
- Ensure that you have passed the proper absolute path of *ChromeDriver* binary through the argument `executable_path`. (chmod 777)
- Execute your *Test* as a **non-root**  user.

Comment: Thanks for reply. Getting another error after i change. Here is the error : OSError: [Errno 8] Exec format error: '/home/cavema11/public_html/chromedriver.exe'

Comment: You are on _Linux OS_ and need to remove the extension part as in `.exe`

Comment: @user9912010 Checkout my updated answer and let me know the status.

Comment: I'm getting this error now "Message: unknown error: cannot find Chrome binary"

Comment: You got _Linux OS_, 1) Which `chromedriver` binary did you download? 2) At which location did you extract it? 3) Did you put the same _absolute location_ of _chromedriver_ binary in your code?

Comment: 1) 2.39
2) in  /public_html
3) driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="/home/cavema11/public_html/chromedriver")

Comment: Within my _Windows OS_ all the variants are shown with `.zip` extension. But as you are on _Linux OS_ you should download `chromedriver_linux64.tar` or `chromedriver_linux64.tz`. Untar it and change the permissions through `chmod 777` first

Comment: Okay, i have untar and change permission to 777 for chromedriver

Comment: What is the status?

Comment: still getting the same error **selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: cannot find Chrome binary**
  **(Driver info: chromedriver=2.39.562737 (dba483cee6a5f15e2e2d73df16968ab10b38a2bf),platform=Linux 3.10.0-862.3.2.el7.x86_64 x86_64)**

Comment: Thanks for your help @DebanjanB

Comment: @user9912010 If you change the original question the answer will not match the updated question and won't be helpful to future readers. Instead raise a new question as per your new requirement. I am reverting back the question to the original version