# Selenium Python Windows "cannot connect to the service"

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I've trawled the web and SO for a good few hours and have exhausted all solutions I can find. Windows 10 / Chrome 87.0 / Python 3.

```
from selenium import webdriver

DRIVER_PATH = r'./chromedriver/chromedriver.exe'
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=DRIVER_PATH)
```

returns:

```
WebDriverException: Message: Can not connect to the Service ./chromedriver/chromedriver.exe
```

- I have made sure that the chromedriver is added to path

  [image]
- I have added 127.0.0.1 localhost to a clean hosts file in `%windir%\System32\drivers\etc`

  [image]
- I have tried specifying the driver path explicitly and implicitly

Answer (score 0):

You need to insert the entire path, on windows its like this:

```
executable_path=r'C:\Utility\BrowserDrivers\chromedriver.exe'
```

Comment: if i used the full windows path i just get a permissions error `executable may have wrong permissions`

Comment: are you admin on your computer?

Comment: yep, i am using the admin account

Comment: thats pretty strange, the error you currently get refers to the fact that you did not insert the full path, so that would technically be the solution i think

Comment: which error, the cannot connect to the service? i always thought that that assumed that the webdriver was found (just by the behaviour - the error takes a few seconds to produce rather than insufficient permissions, or any of the other errors infact, which are instant)

Comment: hmm, that might also be

Answer (score 0):

This *os* path...

```
r'./chromedriver/chromedriver.exe'
```

...refers to the [ChromeDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59909654/how-does-chrome-driver-interact-with-chrome-browser/59927747#59927747) executable within the *chromedriver* sub-directory which is located in the same directory from where your program executes.

By all possible means `r'./chromedriver/chromedriver.exe'` is not the actual location of the *ChromeDriver* executable within your system. Hence you see the error.

---

### Solution

Pass the absolute path of the *ChromeDriver* as follows:

```
from selenium import webdriver

DRIVER_PATH = r'C:\..\..\chromedriver\chromedriver.exe'
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=DRIVER_PATH)
```

---

### References

You can find a couple of relevant detailed discussions in:

- [selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Can not connect to the Service chromedriver.exe while opening chrome browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50727595/selenium-common-exceptions-webdriverexception-message-can-not-connect-to-the-s/50742641#50742641)
- [selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Can not connect to the Service error using ChromeDriver Chrome through Selenium Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59532730/selenium-common-exceptions-webdriverexception-message-can-not-connect-to-the-s/59570386#59570386)
- [Python Selenium “Can not connect to the Service %s” % self.path in linux server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50753093/python-selenium-can-not-connect-to-the-service-s-self-path-in-linux-server/50753175#50753175)

Comment: hi. as mentioned, i have tried the absolute path by using something like this: `full_windows_path = r"c:\webdrivers\chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=full_windows_path)` where i just get an access denied error. i've also tried all solutions in the first of the post you have linked, but havent yet read the second and third (will do now)

Comment: @roastbeeef carefully go through the points mentioned in the _Mandatory Considerations_ sections. I'm sure you will be through.