# Selenium Python code that used to work now opens browser and then gets stuck in "data:,". Says "chrome not reachable"

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome

EDIT: I just realised that I reinstalled Chrome recently, so that might be the problem.

I think Selenium expects to find Chrome in Appdata, but it's not there. I tried copying the Application folder in C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\ to C:\Users\hougy\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome but that doesn't fix it.

I also tried to show it where Chrome is installed but it also doesn't work:

```
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.binary_location = 'C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe'
browser = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
```

I tried variations of the code above and none of them work.

Original question:

My code was working perfectly in the past few months. Then when I ran it yesterday, after downloading the new chromedriver, the browser opens but the webpage does not load, it gets stuck in address "data:,".

Here's a simplified version that has the same problem:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from lxml import etree
import csv
import time
from datetime import datetime
import requests

#options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
#options.add_experimental_option('excludeSwitches', ['enable-logging'])
#options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
#options.add_argument("start-maximized")
#browser = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
browser = webdriver.Chrome()

quote = 'https://www.fundamentus.com.br/detalhes.php?papel=BBAS3'
browser.get(quote)
```

I tried replacing browser = webdriver.Chrome() with the code commented above it because some people here suggested it, but the results are the same. The only difference is that it seems to omit some error messages related to bluetooth that were always there and are not the cause of the problem.

I tried moving to the newest version of Python, then updating pip and redownloading all the libraries. I also updated Chrome and am using the latest stable chromedriver.

I tried running the code in my second PC and it works there with the same Python, Chrome, chromedriver and libraries versions.

Here's what I get when I run it:

```
python .\seleniumTest.py

DevTools listening on ws://192.168.0.104:63785/devtools/browser/5d07327b-ae87-49ee-be00-b9cb0f055b74
[5156:5772:1101/160103.660:ERROR:chrome_browser_main_extra_parts_metrics.cc(230)] crbug.com/1216328: Checking Bluetooth availability started. Please report if there is no 
report that this ends.
[5156:5772:1101/160103.664:ERROR:chrome_browser_main_extra_parts_metrics.cc(233)] crbug.com/1216328: Checking Bluetooth availability ended.
[5156:13960:1101/160103.681:ERROR:device_event_log_impl.cc(214)] [16:01:03.680] Bluetooth: bluetooth_adapter_winrt.cc:1073 Getting Default Adapter failed.
[5156:5772:1101/160103.690:ERROR:chrome_browser_main_extra_parts_metrics.cc(236)] crbug.com/1216328: Checking default browser status started. Please report if there is no 
report that this ends.
[5156:5772:1101/160103.714:ERROR:chrome_browser_main_extra_parts_metrics.cc(240)] crbug.com/1216328: Checking default browser status ended.
[5156:13960:1101/160126.589:ERROR:device_event_log_impl.cc(214)] [16:01:26.588] USB: usb_service_win.cc:258 Failed to get device driver name: Element not found. (0x490)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\hougy\OneDrive\Documentos\plij\seleniumTest.py", line 14, in <module>
    browser = webdriver.Chrome()
  File "C:\Users\hougy\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\chrome\webdriver.py", line 69, in __init__
    super(WebDriver, self).__init__(DesiredCapabilities.CHROME['browserName'], "goog",
  File "C:\Users\hougy\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\chromium\webdriver.py", line 93, in __init__
    RemoteWebDriver.__init__(
  File "C:\Users\hougy\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 266, in __init__
    self.start_session(capabilities, browser_profile)
  File "C:\Users\hougy\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 357, in start_session
    response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, parameters)
  File "C:\Users\hougy\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 418, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Users\hougy\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 243, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: chrome not reachable
Stacktrace:
Backtrace:
        Ordinal0 [0x006006F3+2492147]
        Ordinal0 [0x00599BD1+2071505]
        Ordinal0 [0x004A2340+1057600]
        Ordinal0 [0x0049739D+1012637]
        Ordinal0 [0x004BFF64+1179492]
        Ordinal0 [0x004BC43B+1164347]
        Ordinal0 [0x004B9C9F+1154207]
        Ordinal0 [0x004E9DFF+1351167]
        Ordinal0 [0x004E9A6A+1350250]
        Ordinal0 [0x004E568B+1332875]
        Ordinal0 [0x004C21D4+1188308]
        Ordinal0 [0x004C302F+1191983]
        GetHandleVerifier [0x007867A6+1545030]
        GetHandleVerifier [0x0083105C+2243580]
        GetHandleVerifier [0x0068BC97+518199]
        GetHandleVerifier [0x0068AD80+514336]
        Ordinal0 [0x0059ED2D+2092333]
        Ordinal0 [0x005A2EE8+2109160]
        Ordinal0 [0x005A3022+2109474]
        Ordinal0 [0x005ACB71+2149233]
        BaseThreadInitThunk [0x76736359+25]
        RtlGetAppContainerNamedObjectPath [0x773187A4+228]
        RtlGetAppContainerNamedObjectPath [0x77318774+180]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally solved this after 3 months. I don't think this is what happens to most people that get the same error message, but here's what happened to me:

Surfshark VPN updated their app and the newest versions make my Selenium script unable to find geckodriver and chromedriver. It immediately started working again as soon as I uninstalled the Surfshark app. Just killing the process is not enough.

I am now using Surfshark through the OpenVPN app and this app doesn't prevent my script from working. The Surfshark app has more features but so far I am unable to make both work.

Answer (score 0):

When you previously executed your program the [google-chrome](/questions/tagged/google-chrome) browser and the [ChromeDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59909654/how-does-chrome-driver-interact-with-chrome-browser/59927747#59927747) was in perfect sync. Hence it executed well.

But currently Google Chrome browser being updated to *Version 95.0.4638.69* your program doesn't finds the matching [ChromeDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53727887/what-is-benefit-of-using-chromedriver-over-webdriver-if-we-are-using-only-chrome/53744026#53744026) to drive the Chrome browser.

Hence you see **`data:,`** in the address bar.

---

### Solution

Use the *key* `executable_path` to point to the downloaded matching version of the *ChromeDriver* as follows:

```
browser = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=r'C:\Utility\BrowserDrivers\chromedriver.exe')
```

---

### References

You can find a couple of relevant detailed discussions in:

- [Python Selenium "Can not connect to the Service %s" % self.path in linux server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50753093/python-selenium-can-not-connect-to-the-service-s-self-path-in-linux-server/50753175#50753175)
- [selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Can not connect to the Service error using ChromeDriver Chrome through Selenium Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59532730/selenium-common-exceptions-webdriverexception-message-can-not-connect-to-the-s/59570386#59570386)
- [selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Can not connect to the Service chromedriver.exe while opening chrome browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50727595/selenium-common-exceptions-webdriverexception-message-can-not-connect-to-the-s/50742641#50742641)

Comment: The chromedriver is in the same folder as the python script, so that solution doesn't solve it. I just realised that the problem is that Chrome is now not installed in the default location in Appdata, but so far I am unable to fix it. Please check the edit I will add now to the question

Comment: Either way the error message clearly reflects that, there is a mismatch between _Chrome_ and _ChromeDriver_. Now, which version of which binary you are using should be a separate discussion all together.

Comment: I tried your suggestion and it doesn't work. Using the same ChromeDriver and Chrome versions in my other PC it works. Do you know if what I described in the edit might be the cause?

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't solve it but discovered a workaround: using Firefox and geckodriver. I had many problems before whenever Chrome updated, so I hope this change will improve things because I only use Firefox for this.